# reactjs - Create Toggle For Dynamically Created Buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I am facing a problem with JS/React/React-Native. I am pulling categories from an API, and I am making buttons out of the results (they change often based on different variables in the URL). The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
const cats = singles.map((d) => {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity key={d} style={styles.Settingcats}><Text style={{color: '#f55f44'}}>{d}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

With the dynamically generated buttons I want them to be able to be toggled in the application. When I tried to utilize the states with the following code:

```
const cats = singles.map((d) => {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity key={d} onPress={ _ => this.changeStyle} style={this.state.style === 0 ? styles.Settingcats : styles.SelSettingcats}><Text style={{color: '#f55f44'}}>{d}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

And realized that, since this was referring to one state for all of the buttons, it would change all of the buttons styles. So I tried to think otuside the box a bit and thought of using the ID as a state name, creating the state, and utilizing the state through an external function to change it's value.

```
const cats = singles.map((d) => {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity key={d} onPress={ _ => this.changeStyle(d)} style={this.state([d]) === 0 ? styles.Settingcats : styles.SelSettingcats}><Text style={{color: '#f55f44'}}>{d}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)}
changeStyle(d){
  this.setState({
    [d] : 1
})}
```

Which throws an error because the state is being utilized as if it is a function.

What practices can I use to make dynamically created buttons have their own separate toggle events?

Other things I have tried: Custom Switches, material-UI but I get stuck at the same problem when it comes to having unique functions for the toggled buttons.

Comment: you can access the attributes in state via this.state[d] . Try this. you were calling it as function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that I used to achieve this, with many thanks from @simbathesailor

I utilized the variable in the state to dynamically create states that I could utilize in telling whether the buttons were "on" or "off" by using

```
this.state[d]
```

Where d was the dynamic variable that I created with my TouchableOpaque component.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manage a list of states at the top level, move TouchableOpacity into a component that handles the toggle state internally.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        toggle: false
    }
    this.setToggle = this.setToggle.bind(this);
  }

  setToggle(){
    this.setState({
        toggle: !this.state.toggle
    })
  }

    render(){
    return <TouchableOpacity onClick={this.setToggle} className={this.state.toggle ? 'red' : 'blue'}>{this.props.name}</TouchableOpacity>
  }
}
```

You can render a list of these and each one manages it own toggle state independent of the others.

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/220149/

Comment: how can i move these button on left like when the row is full till the right and any new button is added dynamically on button click